# как сделать перемещение елемента div по клике на button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Этот код работает для перемещения элемента по нажатию на кнопки клавиатуры.

Как сделать, чтобы элемент двигался по клику на кнопки button если их добавить ?

```js
let ball = document.querySelector('.ball');
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

  console.log('key code - ', e.keyCode);
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    let goUp = ball.offsetTop;
    console.log(goUp);
    ball.style.top = goUp - 40 + "px";
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    let goDown = ball.offsetTop
    ball.style.top = goDown + 40 + "px"
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    let goLeft = ball.offsetLeft
    ball.style.left = goLeft - 40 + "px"
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    let goRight = ball.offsetLeft
    ball.style.left = goRight + 40 + "px"
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="ball">Hello </div>
```

Comment: А что вы попробовали уже сами для решения данной задачи?

Comment: Я новичок. Только учусь. Еще не разобрался как скрипт работает с DOM. я пробовал через onclick по buttonу задавать изменения стилей но не работает.
я так понимаю та так же нужно использовать addEventListener но я не знаю как собрать все правильно

Comment: `addEventListener` "вешает" слушатель на элемент к которому применяется (сейчас это `document`,а слушается событие 'keydown' - нажатие кнопки), соответственно вам надо добавить в разметку кнопку, найти её по селектору (как вы нашли div с классом ball) и повесить на него слушатель 'click' - событие клика мышки), внутри убрать условия, так как они для определения того какая именно кнопка была нажата. То есть по сути вы правильно мыслите, вам надо вместо документа вешать на кнопку слушатель и отслеживать клик, а не кейдаун и убрать условия внутри обработчика, это все.

Answer (score 4):

```js
let ball = document.querySelector('.ball');
let upButton = document.querySelector('#up');
let downButton = document.querySelector('#down');
let leftButton = document.querySelector('#left');
let rightButton = document.querySelector('#right');

upButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let goUp = ball.offsetTop;
  ball.style.top = goUp - 40 + "px";
});
downButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 let goDown = ball.offsetTop;
  ball.style.top = goDown + 40 + "px";
});
leftButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let goLeft = ball.offsetLeft;
  ball.style.left = goLeft - 40 + "px";
});
rightButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let goRight = ball.offsetLeft;
  ball.style.left = goRight + 40 + "px";
});

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){

    console.log('key code - ', e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode == 38){
        let goUp = ball.offsetTop;
        console.log(goUp);
        ball.style.top = goUp - 40 + "px";
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 40){
        let goDown = ball.offsetTop
        ball.style.top = goDown + 40 + "px"
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 37){
        let goLeft = ball.offsetLeft
        ball.style.left = goLeft - 40 + "px"
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
        let goRight = ball.offsetLeft
        ball.style.left = goRight + 40 + "px"
    }
})
```

```css
.ball-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball-box">
  <div class="ball"></div>
</div>

<div class="button-box">
  <button id="up">up</button>
  <button id="down">down</button>
  <button id="left">left</button>
  <button id="right">right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: а что такое  keycode?

Comment: Виртуальные коды клавиш http://umi-cms.spb.su/ref/javascript/251/

Comment: О.о спасибо большое

Comment: Если задача решена, то закрывайте пожалуйста вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Добавил кнопку top и два варианта исполнения в ваш код. Выбирайте какой удобен больше (второй закомментирован). Остальные кнопки добавьте подобным образом

```
let topButton = document.querySelector('.top');
topButton.onclick = function() { ball.style.top = ball.offsetTop - 40 + 'px';}
//topButton.addEventListener('click', function(){ball.style.top = ball.offsetTop - 40 + 'px';});
```

```js
let ball = document.querySelector('.ball');
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    console.log('key code - ', e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode == 38){
        let goUp = ball.offsetTop;
        console.log(goUp);
        ball.style.top = goUp - 40 + "px";
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 40){
        let goDown = ball.offsetTop
        ball.style.top = goDown + 40 + "px"
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 37){
        let goLeft = ball.offsetLeft
        ball.style.left = goLeft - 40 + "px"
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
        let goRight = ball.offsetLeft
        ball.style.left = goRight + 40 + "px"
    }
});
let topButton = document.querySelector('.top');
topButton.onclick = function() { ball.style.top = ball.offsetTop - 40 + 'px';}
//topButton.addEventListener('click', function(){ball.style.top = ball.offsetTop - 40 + 'px';});
```

```css
.ball {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>onclick</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ball"></div>
    <button class="top">top</button>
</body>
</html>
```